# c# zedgraph with decimal point instead of comma

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I'm using the zedgraph with c#. Because I have a German Windows, the  X-Axis and Y-Axis have a decimal comma instead of a decimal point. How can I change
it to a decimal point? 
Something like '`myPane.XAxis.Scale.Format = "0.00"`;' did not have any effects.

Answer (score 0):

I use this to force the culture to english. Which applies to the `decimal separator` etc.

```
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");

CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
```

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful!